# how to efficiently find the frame head in much data(6MB) on arm board?

Tags: c++, c, linux, algorithm, arm

I have a problem，how to efficiently find the frame head(such as 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd) in much data(6MB,in a mmap memory) on arm board(a53 cpu). Direct traversal takes a long time.This is my code, i want to get help.

```
for (i = 0, j = len_25per, k = len_50per, m = len_75per; i < len_25per, j < len_50per, k < len_75per, m < cl1_dma->len; i++, j++, k++, m++)
            {
                if (cl1_dma->addr[i] == 0xe5)
                {
                    if (cl1_dma->addr[i + 1] == 0x30)
                    {
                        if ((cl1_dma->addr[i + 4] | cl1_dma->addr[i + 5] << 8) == 0x0023)
                        {
                            if (cl1_dma->addr[i + 10] == 0x13)
                            {
                                find_head = 1;
                                location = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (cl1_dma->addr[j] == 0xe5)
                {
                    if (cl1_dma->addr[j + 1] == 0x30)
                    {
                        if ((cl1_dma->addr[j + 4] | cl1_dma->addr[j + 5] << 8) == 0x0023)
                        {
                            if (cl1_dma->addr[j + 10] == 0x13)
                            {
                                find_head = 1;
                                location = j;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

...

```
            }
```

Comment: I don't know what the values are, but `i < len_25per, j < len_50per, k < len_75per, m < cl1_dma->len;` is almost certainly wrong... the comma operator evaluates whatever's on the left, discards it (so only any side effects are relevant), then continues evaluating what's on the right.  So from all these `<` comparisons, only `m < cl1_cma->len` could terminate the loop.  Perhaps you're wasting time searching extra bytes?

Comment: It may or may not help, but I'd suggest trying [`memchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) to scan for `0xe5`s, then as each is reported checking the following offsets for `0x30`, `0x0023`, `0x13`.  One thing to be careful of there is that a `memchr(cl1_dma->addr, 0xe5, len_25per)` may scan deeper into that region (or possibly scan it all and fail) when there's a match earlier in `memchr(cl1_dma->addr + len_25per, 0xe5, len_50per)` that you may want to continue to use.  Of course, add offsets and shorten search length as you go.

Comment: If you happen to know something about the necessary offset/alignment of the data within the search area, and your CPU is tolerant to and quickly does unaligned reads (true of modern Intel x86s, but not sure about ARM), you could compare `uint16_t` slices of the data to `0xe530` or `0x30e5` - whichever matches your endianness.   Yet another option is to divide the search area and use multiple threads.

Comment: Have you considered Boyer-Moore searching? KMP search? Both are much faster than a simple linear search.

Comment: IMHO, you should search for the first byte.  If found, confirm that the next 3 bytes are correct.  If you are lucky, you may be able to use a SIMD instruction for searching.  You could use `std::find`.

Comment: This is exactly what [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) does, right?  Try that as your benchmark before trying to optimize better than the experts.  Or in C, GNU/Linux systems provide the nonstandard [`memmem`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html) function which also does exactly that.

Comment: thanks everyone. i use Boyer-Moore to find the head data, which works well.